# Large dateset visualization

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have data in `.csv` format, that I imported it as one `data.table` with `dim` = 2500 rows x 41 columns.

Each 41 columns is supposed to be a frame measured at different time intervals (2500 frames). I need to do a heat map in each data frame, and at the end visualize it as a 3D to show each layer separably by going through the layers. Something like this:
[image]

The following codes helped me to split my data, and do what I want to do, except I stil couldn't figure it out how to create a stack of my data frame in 3D cubical model (as I showed in the picture).

```
library(plot.matrix)
df_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2500)
for(i in 1:2500){
df_list[[i]] = snap_movie_1_dat[(1+41*(i-1)):(41*(i)),]}
for(i in 1:2500){
plot(as.matrix(df_list[[i]]))}
```